# Searching based on a changing value in Solr

Tags: solr

Imagine you're creating a website that allows people to search for rental cars based on price, amongst other things.  Some rental cars are more popular at certain times of the year than others, so their price varies based on date.  For instance, a car might cost $90/day most of the year except for December & March, when it costs $110/day, and in January & February it costs $130/day.  Is it possible to have a calculated field in Solr, so you can search for a car that costs less than $X/day over the duration of your rental?  I'm new to Solr, so have absolutely no idea whether this is possible or not - sorry if I'm asking a dumb question.

One possibility that I've come across would be to index the item once for each price, and have start and end dates for each of these.  This copes with the price changes, but won't work for rentals that cross price boundaries; for example, a customer might want to rent a car for one week in February and two weeks in March - we'd end up not finding the car in this case.

I'm using Solr 3.5.  Is it possible to do this using a FunctionQuery?  I've seen some documentation on them, but all the examples I've seen are using them to return a computed value, rather than performing a search on that computed value.  If I can't do this using a FunctionQuery, how could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be possible:

In your index you can have different types of columns containing the different prices of different seasons.  In your query, you need need to use a product on the price during a certain season against the number of days in that season, and sum it to the product on the price during the other season against the number of days in that season.  Yes, you'll have to use FunctionQuery. The means of providing how many days falls into which season that you'll probably have to do on the client that is calling the solr web service.  Furthermore, you can try to apply a filter query on the result to pick out the amount that the user is willing to pay.